# Getting angular directive attribute value returns 'undefined'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm doing a directive for input mask. But, when I pass a string as value the attribute is undefined. If I pass directly the mask It's working.

```
.directive('inputMask', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('inputMask', function (newVal) {
            console.log('inputMask', newVal);
        });
        var maskType = scope.$eval(attrs.inputMask);
        switch (maskType) {
            case 'phone':
                $(element).inputmask("phone", {
                    url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-inputmask/phone-codes/phone-codes.json")',
                    onKeyValidation: function () { //show some metadata in the console
                        console.log($(this).inputmask("getmetadata")["name_en"]);
                    }
                });
                break;
            case 'money':
                $(element).inputmask("decimal", { digits: 2 });
                break;
            case 'moneyGrouped':
                $(element).inputmask("decimal", {
                    radixPoint: ",",
                    autoGroup: true,
                    groupSeparator: ".",
                    groupSize: 3,
                    digits: 2
                });
                break;
            case 'email':
                $(element).inputmask('Regex', { regex: "[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}" });
            default:
                $(element).inputmask(maskType);
        }

        $(element).inputmask(scope.$eval(attrs.inputMask));
        $(element).on('keypress', function () {
            scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel + "='" + element.val() + "'");
        });
    }
};
});
```

Working (will get into default of the switch):

```
<input type="teste" name="teste" value="" ng-model="form.email" input-mask='{ "mask": "d/m/y", "autoUnmask" : true}'/>
```

Not working, **attrs.inputMask** is `undefined` (should enter in case 'money'):

```
<input type="teste" name="teste" value="" ng-model="form.email" input-mask='money'/>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This isn't your answer, but for googlers one thing to check is your camelcased scope parameters are expected to be spinal case in html when using shorthand syntax '='

Comment: Please do this in your $watch - console.log(typeof newVal);, and check for two cases. Please revert back then I may solve the problem. Or provide a fiddle for this.

Comment: thanks, fiat! this was the problem in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `scope: true` a new scope will be created for this directive. Then, to your `$watch` works correctly, you should create a new attribute to the current scope, called inputMask, that receives the `attrs.inputMask`

```
scope.inputMask = attrs.inputMask;
scope.$watch('inputMask', function (newVal) {
    console.log('inputMask', newVal);
});
```

You can see a simplified Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/790/)

The other option, is to use the a hash object in directive's scope attribute.

The [directive docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) writes:

> {} (object hash) - a new 'isolate' scope is created. The 'isolate'
>   scope differs from normal scope in that it does not prototypically
>   inherit from the parent scope. This is useful when creating reusable
>   components, which should not accidentally read or modify data in the
>   parent scope.
>
> (...)
>
> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of a DOM attribute.

That way, you can create your scope binding the DOM attribute:

```
scope: { 
    inputMask: "@" 
},
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('inputMask', function (newVal) {
        console.log('inputMask', newVal);
    });
    /* ... */
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/791/)

Comment: attrs.inputMask still undefined using this.

Comment: Did you check the fiddles? What is your angular version?

Comment: check your self, just write the value of inputMask when you set as inputMask='phone' for exemple, is undefined

Answer (score 0):

In the directive use,

scope: {inputMask: '@'}

And in the link function instead of using attr.inputMask use scope.inputMask and that will work.

If you want to use attr then you can use

```
attr.$observe('inputMask', function() {
    console.log('changed');
}
```

Because initially the value will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem here was that scope.$eval('money') will return undefined.
The attribute should be linking just fine to the directive, if it's in curly braces {}, or if it's a string such as 'money'.

It's what you're doing with the value that's causing the problem.

```
var maskType = scope.$eval(attrs.inputMask);
```

You would only need to use isolated scope with @, or attrs.$observe if you were passing interpolated attributes, such as {{money}}.